# Combine and Display query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 query:

```
SELECT CustomerID,count(b.BookingStatus) as 'NotComplete'
FROM Booking b, Customer c 
WHERE c.CustomerID=b.BookingCustomerID
AND(b.BookingStatus='Pending'
OR b.BookingStatus='OTW')
GROUP BY c.CustomerID


SELECT c.CustomerID, r.*
FROM Customer c,Regular r
WHERE c.CustomerID=r.RegularCID
Result:
```

1st query [image]

2nd query[image]

How to combine these 2 result together?

also, display the zero(count) as well.

Thanks!

---

this is what I get after few hours of trying..obviously it's not what I want..

```
SELECT c.CustomerID,count(b.BookingStatus) as 'NotComplete',r.RegularID
FROM Booking b, Customer c 
JOIN Regular r on r.RegularCID=c.CustomerID
WHERE c.CustomerID=b.BookingCustomerID

AND (b.BookingStatus='Pending'
or b.BookingStatus='OTW'
or b.BookingStatus='Started'
or b.BookingStatus='Unclaimed'
or b.BookingStatus='Confirmed')
GROUP by r.RegularID
```

Comment: Is there always one and only one `RegularID` per `CustomerID`?

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: @Nick ya.. only RegularID per CustomerID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` to the `Regular` table and then `LEFT JOIN` to a derived table of counts in the `Booking` table. We do it this way to avoid having to `GROUP BY` all the columns in the `Regular` table:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, r.*, b.NotComplete
FROM Customer c
JOIN Regular r ON r.RegularCID = c.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT BookingCustomerID, COUNT(*) AS NotComplete
           FROM Booking
           WHERE BookingStatus IN ('Pending', 'OTW', 'Started', 'Unclaimed', 'Confirmed')
           GROUP BY BookingCustomerID) b ON b.BookingCustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Comment: What if 1 CustomerID having multiple RegularID ? I appreciate your reply. thx

Comment: @wayne9003 you will get multiple rows in the output, one for each `RegularID`.

Comment: @wayne9003 the query can be modified to give whatever result you need though..

Comment: I'm figuring about if 1 CustomerID having multiple RegularID...can you guide me to get the query?

Comment: @wayne9003 it depends on what result you want. Do you want separate lines, or do you want perhaps the `RegularID` values separated by commas? What about the other values in the `Regular` table? Do you want them and if so, do you want both sets of values? As you can see, there are a lot of variables. It might be easier to ask a new question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203304/discussion-between-wayne9003-and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

Use join on `regular` table, and `subquery` on your first `select`

```
SELECT t1.*, r.RegularCID FROM (
    SELECT CustomerID,count(b.BookingStatus) as 'NotComplete',
    FROM Booking b
    INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.CustomerID=b.BookingCustomerID
    WHERE (b.BookingStatus='Pending' OR b.BookingStatus='OTW')
    GROUP BY c.CustomerID) t1
LEFT JOIN Regular r on r.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
```